# Count values for past x days in groups

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble writing this in a more pythonic and efficient manner. I'm trying to group observations by customerid and count the number of times for each observation that the customer was declined in the past 1, 7 and 30 days.

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'customerid': [1,1,1,3,3],
                 'leadid': [10,11,12,13,14], 
                 'postdate': ["2017-01-25 10:55:25.727", "2017-02-02 10:55:25.727", "2017-02-27 10:55:25.727", "2017-01-25 10:55:25.727", "2017-01-25 11:55:25.727"], 
                 'post_status': ['Declined', 'Declined', 'Declined', 'Declined', 'Declined']})
t['postdate'] = pd.to_datetime(t['postdate'])
```

Here is the output:

```
customerid  leadid  post_status postdate
1   10  Declined    2017-01-25 10:55:25.727
1   11  Declined    2017-02-02 10:55:25.727
1   12  Declined    2017-02-27 10:55:25.727
3   13  Declined    2017-01-25 10:55:25.727
3   14  Declined    2017-01-25 11:55:25.727
```

My current solution is very slow:

```
final = []
for customer in t['customerid'].unique():

    temp = t[(t['customerid']==customer) & (t['post_status']=='Declined')].copy()

    for i, row in temp.iterrows():
        date = row['postdate']
        final.append({
            'leadid': row['leadid'],
            'decline_1': temp[(temp['postdate'] <= date) & (temp['postdate']>=date-timedelta(days=1))].shape[0]-1,
            'decline_7': temp[(temp['postdate'] <= date) & (temp['postdate']>=date-timedelta(days=7))].shape[0]-1,
            'decline_30': temp[(temp['postdate'] <= date) & (temp['postdate']>=date-timedelta(days=30))].shape[0]-1
        })
```

The expected output is shown below:

```
decline_1   decline_30  decline_7   leadid
0   0   0   10
0   1   0   11
0   1   0   12
0   0   0   13
1   1   1   14
```

I imagine I need some sort of double groupby where I iterate over each row in the group, but I'm unable to get anything to work other than this double for-loop which takes very long to complete.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `groupby` and `transform` and using the fact that the sum of a boolean array is the number of `True`s, so you don't need to generate an extra DataFrame to do something like this `temp[(temp['postdate'] <= date) & (temp['postdate']>=date-timedelta(days=7))].shape[0]-1` every time:

```
def find_declinations(df, period):
    results = pd.Series(index=df.index, name=period)
    for index, date in df.items():
        time_range = df.between(date - period, date)
        results[index] = time_range.sum() - 1
    return results.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

and call it like this

```
results = pd.DataFrame(index=t.index)
period=pd.to_timedelta(1, 'd')
for days in [1, 7, 30]:
    results['decline%i'% days] = t.groupby('customerid')[['postdate']].transform(lambda x: find_declinations(x, pd.to_timedelta(days, 'd')))
results.index = t['leadid']
```

> results

```
    decline1    decline7    decline30
leadid          
10  0   0   0
11  0   0   1
12  0   0   1
13  0   0   0
14  1   1   1
```

## slightly different approach

That appoach does a groupby per period. You can speed it up by only doing 1 groupby and then calculate all periods for each group

```
def find_declinations_df(df, periods = [1, 7, 30, 60]):
#     print(periods, type(df), df)
    results = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.DataFrame(df).index, columns=periods)
    for period in periods: 
        for index, date in df['postdate'].items():
            time_range = df['postdate'].between(date - pd.to_timedelta(period, 'd'), date)
            results.loc[index, period] = time_range.sum() - 1
    return results.fillna(0).astype(int)

results = pd.concat(find_declinations_df(group[1]) for group in t.groupby('customerid'))
results['leadid'] = t['leadid']
```

> results

```
    1   7   30  60  leadid
0   0   0   0   0   10
1   0   0   1   1   11
2   0   0   1   2   12
3   0   0   0   0   13
4   1   1   1   1   14
```